# Nginx Configuration Versioning Strategy

Tags: linux, git, nginx, version-control, config

currently a project my team inherited has a complete mess on the nginx configuration across 10+ environments, we would like to implement a versioning strategy however im not sure how people "normally" achieve this. you make the whole nginx conf folder a git repo and ignore what you do not want to version? or have a separate folder with the config file repo and deploy the files with a script?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

We manage it via separate Git repository exclusive only for nginx configuration. Yes, it includes everything inside `/etc/nginx/` directory.

But it's not synced directly on server, instead a bash script is used to pull changes, update configuration, and reload nginx configuration.

Script example:

```
# Pull changes
git pull

# Sync changes excluding .git directory
rsync -qauh ./* "/etc/nginx" --exclude=".git"

# Set proper permissions
chmod -R 644 /etc/nginx
find /etc/nginx -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \;

# If you store SSL certs under `/etc/nginx/ssl`
# Set proper permission for SSL certs 
chmod -R 600 /etc/nginx/ssl
chmod -R 400 /etc/nginx/ssl/*

# Reload nginx config
# but only if configtest is passed
nginx -t && service nginx reload
```

Comment: so basically you have it on another folder (the git repo), work on that folder, commitpush it, then a script  will pull changes, update configuration, and reload nginx configuration? sorry, i just want to make sure i understand your solution 100%, btw thanks!

Comment: @JuanSebastian right, you understood me correctly. It's made this way to have an ability to set permissions properly and exclude `.git` directory

Comment: Isn't permissions preserved via git?

Comment: @thomthom yes! This is for the case when we don't care about permissions unless delivered to server. And looks more intuitive in example than setting permissions first then push/pull, different hosts, this is just simpler way to explain my solution